# Can’t read JSON from CDC in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to read data in JSON format from CDC (YugabyteDB 2.13) for which I've used the following configuration:

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.yugabytedb.YugabyteDBConnector
database.streamid=88433e52543c4ecdb20934c6135beb3f
database.user=yugabyte
database.dbname=yugabyte
tasks.max=7
database.server.name=dbserver1
database.port=5433
database.master.addresses=<ip>:7100
database.hostname=<hostname>
database.password=yugabyte
table.include.list= sch.test
snapshot.mode=never
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

But I am unable to display data in JSON format. In fact the connector fails due

```
Schema for table 'sch.test' is missing (io.debezium.connector.yugabytedb.YugabyteDBChangeRecordEmitter:290)
[Worker-070086c4d98efddbd] [2022-04-12 11:04:15,978] ERROR [qorbital-test-json-msk|task-0] Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:31)
[Worker-070086c4d98efddbd] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while processing event at offset {transaction_id=null,
```

Is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was with the version of YugabyteDB you were using (2.13.0), once it was released, there was a bug related to connector restarts which were causing a `NullPointerException` as the schema that is cached in the Debezium connector object was not persistent across the restart. So to fix the bug, we have added the logic to send the schema from the server-side every time there’s a restart or whenever the connector requests for the same, this will help in caching the schema and thus would resolve the NPE. Upgrading to a newer version will fix the issue.